# Google API to check if new version of app has been deployed

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application

I have an app on the Google Playstore and I want a way to alert my users whenever I deploy a new version of the app. I want to know how to make this possible. Does Google Playstore provide any APIs or SDKs to make this possible?

I use React-native for development, incase the answer may depend on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Playstore supports this feature named [In-app-updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)

There is no official implementation for this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#guides), but take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-in-app-updates).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)**:

> In-app updates is a Google Play Core libraries feature that prompts
> active users to update your app.

There are mainly two update flows.

- [Flexible updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#flexible)
- [Immediate updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#immediate)

Here is a detailed guide that describes how to [support in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java) in your app.